# Background Colour for views set in Storyboard is not working properly?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, uicolor

Strange Issue.

When I set background colour for UIView, UILabel or UIButton from **Storyboard** it is showing as below

[image]

But When I set background color using programming like below,
`customView.backgroundColor = //Same colour which I set in storyboard` for same views, it is showing as below:
[image]

**Check Colour difference for same RGB values**

Also, For navigation bar with same tint colour and nil background image it is showing like below

`self.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(nil, for: .default)
 self.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.nbRedColor()`

[image]

And when I set translucent property to false, it is shwoing as below:
`self.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false`

[image]

I understand the navigation bar different colour thing is due to isTranslucent flag. But why is background colour of views from storyboard and programming is differnet.

*(Background colour from Programming is correct one)*

Xcode Version 8.3.3 (Tested in both simulator and multiple devices)

[image]

Comment: how you get Color RGB value ?

Comment: please share how to set RGB color

Comment: share screenshot from where you set color in storyboard

Comment: @MoinShirazi updated question

Comment: it seems fine, please check your view alpha.

Comment: Checked everything

Comment: Now I tried sRGB, and it's working fine. Is there anyway I can change it everywhere in one go?

Comment: @Jaydip question updated

Comment: @SaraMethuz question updated

Comment: use ADOBE RGB(1998)

Answer (score 2):

You can make it correct on the StoryBoard Also like this

Just Select Adobe RGB in that and paste your hex color in that box and you done!

if any issue please let me know..

[image]